# Powershell: Script to search all user profiles and copy the most recent to all user profiles

Tags: powershell, xenapp

I am looking to write a powershell script to search all user profiles on a server for a specific file, compare the files by the lastmodifieddate, and then copy the newest file to all user profiles. The script will also create a backup of the last three versions of the file.

I previously wrote this script for our pilot environment where only two people were accessing the app (this is for a XenApp), but the user base has now expanded and I would like to create the prod version of the script to cover future growth.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!  Script below...

```
$SRC1 = "\\Server\c$\Users\XXXX1\AppData\Roaming\EMIESiteListManager\sitelist.xml"
$SRC2 = "\\Server\c$\Users\XXXX2\AppData\Roaming\EMIESiteListManager\sitelist.xml"
$SRC3 = "\\Server\c$\Users\XXXX3\AppData\Roaming\EMIESiteListManager\sitelist.xml"
$BKU = "\\storage\IT\EMSLM\Backup"

if ( (get-item $SRC1).LastWriteTime -gt (get-item $SRC2).LastWriteTime )  {Copy-Item $SRC1 $SRC2}
    else {Copy-Item $SRC2 $SRC1}

if ( (get-item $SRC1).LastWriteTime -gt (get-item $SRC3).LastWriteTime )  {Copy-Item $SRC1 $SRC3}
    else {Copy-Item $SRC3 $SRC1}

if ( (get-item $SRC1).LastWriteTime -gt (get-item $SRC2).LastWriteTime )  {Copy-Item $SRC1 $SRC2}


Remove-Item $BKU\sitelist_old_2.xml
Rename-Item $BKU\sitelist_old_1.xml $BKU\sitelist_old_2.xml
Rename-Item $BKU\sitelist.xml $BKU\sitelist_old_1.xml
Copy-Item $SRC1 $BKU

& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Mode Site List Manager\EMIESiteListManager.exe'

Exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn't everything, but it should be a good place to start

```
$users = dir "\\Server\c$\Users" -Directory | select -ExpandProperty fullname
$newest = dir "\\Server\c$\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\EMIESiteListManager\sitelist.xml" | sort lastwritetime -Descending | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty fullname

$files = @()

$users | % {
    $files += $newest -replace [regex]::Escape($_)
}

$newestEnd = $files | sort {$_.length} | select -f 1

$users | % {
    $dest = Join-Path $_ $newestEnd
    copy $newest $dest -force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working off of Anthony Stringer's response I was able to build a script that meets my exact needs. Anthony's script would have worked, but was missing a couple things that I wanted:

1.) Identify all profiles with an existing sitelist.xml file and place in an array or hash table.

2.) Copy only to those user profiles where the sitelist.xml file existed (my fault, I never requested this in my original question)

Thank you Anthony for the starting point.  Updated script below:

```
$Users = dir "\\server\c$\Users" -Directory -Exclude Public, Default, Administrator* | select -ExpandProperty fullname
$FilePath = "AppData\Roaming\EMIESiteListManager\sitelist.xml"
$UserPath = Join-Path -path $Users $filePath
$NewestFile = dir "\\server\c$\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\EMIESiteListManager\sitelist.xml" | sort lastwritetime -Descending | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty fullname
$BackUp = "\\storage\ctxvol01\appdata\IT\EMSLM\Backup"
$BackUpFile = "\\storage\ctxvol01\appdata\IT\EMSLM\Backup\sitelest.xml"

$EMSLM_Users = @()

$UserPath | ForEach {
    If ((Test-Path -path $_) -eq $true)
        {$EMSLM_Users += $_}
    }

$EMSLM_Users | ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item $NewestFile $_ -force -erroraction silentlycontinue
    }

If ($NewestFile.lastwritetime -gt $BackUpFile.lastwritetime)
    {
        Remove-Item $BackUp\sitelist_old_2.xml -and Rename-Item $BackUp\sitelist_old_1.xml $BackUp\sitelist_old_2.xml -and Rename-Item $BackUp\sitelist.xml $BackUp\sitelist_old_1.xml -and Copy-Item $NewestFile $BackUp
    }

& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Mode Site List Manager\EMIESiteListManager.exe'

Exit
```